# Should a function be async if it does not use await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, eslint

Consider a javascript function that is essentially a wrapper for another async function. Should that wrapping function necessarily be async itself, even if it does need need to await the underlying promise?

Here's a simple example:

```
function myWrapperFunction() {
    console.log('Calling myAsyncFunction')
    return myAsyncFunction();
}

async function myAsyncFunction() {
    const url = 'URL'
    const data = await fetch(url)
    return JSON.parse(data)
}
```

Should `myWrapperFunction` be `async`? I would guess it doesn't need to be given that it just returns the promise from `myAsyncFunction`. However the first example in the correct code section of es-lint's `no-return-await` rule hints otherwise:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, misread the code ... no `myWrapperFunction` doesn't need to be `async` ... but it still returns a Promise, not the `result` you're looking for

Comment: misread it again :p that first example looks wrong ... unless `bar()` can return either a Promise or a value ... then, function foo will ALWAYS return a Promise, making the calling code to foo() much simpler

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like that:

```js
function myWrapperFunction() {
    console.log('Calling myAsyncFunction')
    const promise = myAsyncFunction();
    return promise;
}
```

to improve maintainability of the code. E.g. to ensure other people wouldn't need to ask themselves whether returning a Promise is intentional or not.